# Create an empty file on the commandline in windows (like the linux touch command)

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-line

On a windows machine I get this error

> 'touch' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I was following these [instructions](https://makerlog.org/posts/leaflet-basics) which seem to be linux specific, but on a standard windows commandline it does not work like this:

```
touch index.html app.js style.css
```

Is there a windows equivalent of the 'touch' command from the linux / mac os / unix world ? Do I need to create these files by hand (and modify them to change the timestamp) in order to implement this sort of command? I am working with node and that doesn't seem very ... node-ish...

Comment: A [simple Google search](https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en#hl=en&q=touch+unix+program+for+windows) shows you lots of windows implementations of `touch`.  Other discussion here: http://superuser.com/questions/10426/windows-equivalent-of-the-linux-command-touch and the [Cygwin library](https://www.cygwin.com/) is a common toolset of Unix commands on Windows.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26343974/create-file-with-command-line-in-node

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create file with command line in Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26343974/create-file-with-command-line-in-node)

Comment: Please jump to [Raghuveer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53149762/465053) directly if you've landed here while using PowerShell.

Comment: Related post - [Equivalent of Linux `touch` to create an empty file with PowerShell?](https://superuser.com/q/502374/374397)

Comment: If using the PowerShell prompt:
```
    New-Item index.html -Type File
```
or, the built-in short-cut:
```
    ni index.html
```

Answer (score 451):

An easy way to replace the touch command on a windows command line like cmd would be:

```
type nul > your_file.txt
```

This will create 0 bytes in the `your_file.txt` file.

This would also be a good solution to use in windows batch files.

Another way of doing it is by using the [echo](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490897.aspx) command:

```
echo.> your_file.txt
```

echo. - will create a file with one empty line in it.

---

If you need to preserve the content of the file use `>>` instead of `>`

```
>   Creates a new file
>>  Preserves content of the file
```

Example

```
type nul >> your_file.txt
```

---

You can also use [call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/call) command.

> Calls one batch program from another without stopping the parent batch program. The call command accepts labels as the target of the call.

Example:

```
call >> your_file.txt
```

---
or even if you don't want make it hard you can Just install [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490897.aspx) (WSL). Then, type.

```
wsl touch
```

or

```
wsl touch textfilenametoedit.txt
```

Quotes are not needed.

Comment: on windows 7 the first option produces a scary dialog, and then you see `access denied` in the console. The second option works just fine!

Comment: The answer is wrong, it only works when the file does not exist. If the file exists, using `>>` the first does nothing, the second adds a line at the end of the file. The correct answer is https://superuser.com/questions/10426/windows-equivalent-of-the-linux-command-touch/764721#764721

Comment: @stenci - I just tried it on a non-existent file and it worked just fine. It created the file ok. Maybe you lack admin rights?

Comment: @stenci that superuser link is great.  You should post it as an answer.

Comment: @DeniseSkidmore Thanks, I added the answer. It's down deep and people will more likely read my comment to this answer than my answer, but now it's there.

Comment: Indeed, like @stensi said: `type nul >> existing_file.txt` does nothing.

Comment: i always use the "call" internal command: `call >> somefile.txt`
this will create a new file if the file did not exist before; and updates the file's modification time if the file did exists. the "echo" command is very special, as mentioned above: one cannot use it to create and empty file.
the `type nul` command is also a good one. (but as much as five characters longer than a simple `call`)

Comment: can this just be marked as the right answer.

Comment: It;'s 2022 and this is still the best answer

Answer (score 87):

Windows does not natively include a `touch` command.

You can use any of the available public versions or you can use your own version. Save this code as `touch.cmd` and place it somewhere in your path

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    (for %%a in (%*) do if exist "%%~a" (
        pushd "%%~dpa" && ( copy /b "%%~nxa"+,, & popd )
    ) else (
        type nul > "%%~fa"
    )) >nul 2>&1
```

It will iterate over it argument list, and for each element if it exists, update the file timestamp, else, create it.

Comment: this one's the best, works exactly as expected... other solutions here do work but leave warning/error texts, IDK if that exclusive to me.

Answer (score 51):

You can use this command: ECHO >> filename.txt

it will create a file with the given extension in the current folder.

**UPDATE:**

for an empty file use: **copy NUL filename.txt**

Comment: Even better `type NUL > filename` (creates a 0 bytes file)

Comment: Like touch, this will not overwrite the file if it exists: `type NUL >> filename`

Comment: This is a great way to add "ECHO is on." to your file.

Comment: this doesn't update the timestamp of existing files.

Comment: I think Denise Skidmore is responding to henon, not OP.
(I second her comment.)

Answer (score 43):

On windows Power Shell, you can use the following command:

```
New-Item <filename.extension>
```

or

```
New-Item <filename.extension> -type file
```

> Note: **New-Item** can be replaced with its alias **ni**

Comment: This is the real answer in today's Windows world where PowerShell is the default command shell program.

Comment: not sure what Windows you are referring to, I just installed a fresh Windows 10 and Powershell is definitely not the default shell. `'New-Item' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

Comment: This is the best answer for PowerShell 5 on Windows 7.

Comment: You might want to add `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` for existing files, so it doesn't error out on existing files.

Comment: Finally this works!

Answer (score 33):

The answer is wrong, it only works when the file does not exist. If the file exists, using the first does nothing, the second adds a line at the end of the file.

The correct answer is:

```
copy /b filename.ext +,,
```

I found it here: https://superuser.com/questions/10426/windows-equivalent-of-the-linux-command-touch/764721#764721

Comment: This answer does not work when the file does not exist. (CMD produces an error.)

Comment: this is a great solution... and file not existing is easy solved with "if file exist ..."

Answer (score 24):

I'm surprised how many answers here are just *wrong*. Echoing nothing into a file will fill the file with something like `ECHO is ON`, and trying to echo `$nul` into a file will literally place `$nul` into the file. Additionally for PowerShell, echoing `$null` into a file won't actually make a 0kb file, but something encoded as `UCS-2 LE BOM`, which can get messy if you need to make sure your files don't have a byte-order mark.

After testing all the answers here and referencing some similar ones, I can guarantee these will work per console shell. Just change `FileName.FileExtension` to the full or relative-path of the file you want to `touch`; thanks to [Keith Russell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3225396/keith-russell) for the `COPY NUL FILE.EXT` update:

### CMD w/Timestamp Updates

`copy NUL FileName.FileExtension`

This will create a new file named whatever you placed instead of `FileName.FileExtension` with a size of 0 bytes. If the file already exists it will basically copy itself in-place to update the timestamp. I'd say this is more of a workaround than 1:1 functionality with `touch` but I don't know of any built-in tools for CMD that can accomplish updating a file's timestamp without changing any of its other content.

### CMD  w/out Timestamp Updates

`if not exist FileName.FileExtension copy NUL FileName.FileExtension`

### Powershell w/Timestamp Updates

`if (!(Test-Path FileName.FileExtension -PathType Leaf)) {New-Item FileName.FileExtension -Type file} else {(ls FileName.FileExtension ).LastWriteTime = Get-Date}`

Yes, it will work in-console as a one-liner; no requirement to place it in a PowerShell script file.

### PowerShell  w/out Timestamp Updates

`if (!(Test-Path FileName.FileExtension -PathType Leaf)) {New-Item FileName.FileExtension -Type file}`

Comment: What about the situation where the file exists and you want to update its modification timestamp to the current time? I don't see how these examples achieve that.

Comment: Great observation, RoG! I've updated the answer to address this :)

Comment: This is the best answer.
However, I'd still improve it by replacing `fsutil file CreateNew FileName.FileExtension 0` by `copy NUL Filename.FileExtension`, since the latter is shorter and does the same thing.

Comment: @KeithRussell IIRC there was a specific reason I didn't use `copy` over `fsutil` but it's been a while... I'm pretty sure that's how I even learned about `fsutil` haha! I'll try to figure out why...

Comment: Even if they do behave the same, I guess it’s premature for me to say one is better, without speed-testing.

Comment: Nope, that was for not using `copy /b File.Ext +,,` due to not working when it didn't exist. `copy NUL File.ext` does actually work when it doesn't exist so thanks for the heads up! Updating it now :)

Comment: My Powershell told me it could find the NUL filepath because it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 20):

Use the following command on the your command line:

```
fsutil file createnew filename  requiredSize
```

The parameters info as followed:

fsutil - File system utility ( the executable you are running )

file - triggers a file action

createnew - the action to perform (create a new file)

filename - would be literally the name of the file

requiredSize - would allocate a file size in bytes in the created file

Comment: Some explanation is required for this to be considered a decent answer.  It is not clear what these five words mean.

Comment: people might not like this answer, but this is how you create a file in windows. echoing is also possible - but this is the equivalent of touch

Comment: worked for me ... the requiredSize thing is weird though ... the command just fills your new file with thousands of `NULL`s ... weird ... so just use 0 ... generates an error if you skip the requiredSize ...

Comment: this commnad needs admin privilages :(

Comment: touch also updates the timestamp on existing files, not just creates new files.

Comment: touch is a quick way of doing it, closest to it would be echo or type, I guess, although this is a very handy tool for scripting and vastly used in WS16, thumbs up! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/fsutil

Answer (score 16):

install npm on you machine

run the below command in you command prompt.

```
npm install touch-cli -g
```

now you will be able to use touch cmd.

Comment: nodejs devs will love your answer

Comment: the epitome of "- how should I transport my little kitten...                           -well citizen... first buy a transatlantic... then... PROCEED!!!" ;-)))

Answer (score 9):

You can replicate the functionality of touch with the following command:

```
$>>filename
```

What this does is attempts to execute a program called `$`, but if `$` does not exist (or is not an executable that produces output) then no output is produced by it. It is essentially a hack on the functionality, however you will get the following error message:

> '$' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

If you don't want the error message then you can do one of two things:

```
type nul >> filename
```

Or:

```
$>>filename 2>nul
```

The `type` command tries to display the contents of nul, which does nothing but returns an EOF (end of file) when read.

`2>nul` sends error-output (output 2) to nul (which ignores all input when written to). Obviously the second command (with `2>nul`) is made redundant by the `type` command since it is quicker to type. But at least you now have the option and the knowledge.

Comment: This is great, but it sets `%ERRORLEVEL%` to non-zero always. You could fix that problem by appending a noop `|| cd.`, but this always sets the error to 0, which might not be what you want if the "touch" fails.

Answer (score 6):

as mentioned

```
echo >> index.html
```

it can be any file, with any extension
then do

```
notepad index.html
```

this will open your file in the notepad editor

Answer (score 6):

Using PowerShell, type: `ni index.html` or `ni style.css` or `ni app.js`

```
ni <filename>.<extension>
```

Comment: Powershell commands are different from CMD

Comment: Also, `ni` is an alias for `New-Item`. Such clarity is helpful in stackoverflow answers.

Answer (score 5):

No command – neither `type`nor `echo`– is necessary to emulate Unix's/Mac OS X's 'touch' command in a Windows Powershell terminal. Simply use the following shorthand:

```
$null > filename
```

This will create an empty file named 'filename' at your current location. Use any filename extension that you might need, e.g. '.txt'.

Source: https://superuser.com/questions/502374/equivalent-of-linux-touch-to-create-an-empty-file-with-powershell (see comments)

Comment: it looks like you missed `echo`

Comment: @sabithpocker in Windows cmd, $null doesn't exist, and since it does not exist it does not produce any output. You `$null > filename` sends that empty output to _filename_ (if you catch my drift).

Comment: @sabithpocker In Windows Powershell it works without `echo`
In the standard command line terminal (cmd) you need `echo`. 
Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @OliverSchafeld and Keldon Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: This adds a BOM to the file.

Answer (score 5):

For a very simple version of `touch` which would be mostly used to create a 0 byte file in the current directory, an alternative would be creating a `touch.bat` file and either adding it to the `%Path%` or copying it to the `C:\Windows\System32` directory, like so:

**touch.bat**

```
@echo off
powershell New-Item %* -ItemType file
```

**Creating a single file**

```
C:\Users\YourName\Desktop>touch a.txt

    Directory: C:\Users\YourName\Desktop

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----        2020-10-14  10:28 PM              0 a.txt
```

**Creating multiple files**

```
C:\Users\YourName\Desktop>touch "b.txt,c.txt"

    Directory: C:\Users\YourName\Desktop

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----        2020-10-14  10:52 PM              0 b.txt
-a----        2020-10-14  10:52 PM              0 c.txt
```

**Also**

- Works both with PowerShell and the Command Prompt.
- Works with existing subdirectories.
- Does not create a file if it already exists:

```
New-Item : The file 'C:\Users\YourName\Desktop\a.txt' already exists.
```

- For multiple files, creates only the files that do not exist.

  - Accepts a comma-separated list of filenames without spaces or enclosed in quotes if spaces are necessary:

```
C:\Users\YourName\Desktop>touch d.txt,e.txt,f.txt
C:\Users\YourName\Desktop>touch "g.txt, 'name with spaces.txt'"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [copy con [filename]](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/c/copycon.htm) in a Windows command window (cmd.exe):

```
C:\copy con yourfile.txt [enter]
C:\CTRL + Z [enter] //hold CTRL key & press "Z" then press Enter key.
^Z
    1 Files Copied.
```

This will create a file named `yourfile.txt` in the local directory.

Answer (score 3):

I use `cmder` (a command line emulator)

It allows you to run all Linux commands inside a Windows machine.

It can be downloaded from https://cmder.net/

I really like it

Comment: what's up with the "Unknown Publisher" warning when I try to open Cmder in win10?  Bummer.

Answer (score 3):

From the Terminal of Visual Code Studio on Windows 10, this is what worked for me to create a new file:

```
type > hello.js
echo > orange.js
ni > peach.js
```

Answer (score 3):

As [Raghuveer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1359721/raghuveer) points out in his/her [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53149762/138938), `ni` is the PowerShell alias for `New-Item`, so you can create files from a PowerShell prompt using `ni` instead of touch.

If you prefer to type `touch` instead of `ni`, you can set a `touch` alias to the PowerShell `New-Item` cmdlet.

Creating a **touch** command in Windows PowerShell:

From a PowerShell prompt, define the new alias.

```
Set-Alias -Name touch -Value New-Item
```

Now the touch command works *almost* the same as you are expecting. The only difference is that you'll need to separate your list of files with commas.

```
touch index.html, app.js, style.css
```

Note that this only sets the alias for PowerShell. If PowerShell isn't your thing, you can set up WSL or use bash for Windows.

Unfortunately the alias will be forgotten as soon as you end your PowerShell session. To make the alias permanent, you have to add it to your PowerShell user profile.

From a PowerShell prompt:

```
notepad $profile
```

Add your alias definition to your profile and save.

Answer (score 2):

If you have [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/) installed in your PC, you can simply use the supplied executable for **touch** (also via windows command prompt):

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\touch.exe <file_path>
```

Comment: my usual solution for integrating linux commands... my killer-command for this is grep... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the file exists and you just need to update the timestamp.

```
type test.c > test.c.bkp && type test.c.bkp > test.c && del test.c.bkp
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `rem. > file.txt` (notice the dot attached to the command "rem")

this creates an empty file

Answer (score 1):

Shortest possible vanilla solution is :

`.>myfile.txt`

[image]

You will get an error , but file is created :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `type` instead of `touch`:

```
type nul > YOUR_FILE_NAME
```

However, it is limited to just a single file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VS Code, there is a [command line tool](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line) `code` to help you open a non-exist file in VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

There is something missing in all of the other answers. The Linux `touch` command has a `-t` option, which lets you set the last modified time to any arbitrary date and time, not just the current time.

This sets the modification date of `filename.txt` to 20 December 2012 at 30 minutes after midnight.

```
touch -t 201212210030 filename.txt
```

To get the equivalent in Windows, you need to be in **PowerShell**, it can't be done in Cmd.

- Change the **creation** date/timestamp of a file named `filename.txt`:

```
(Get-Item "D:\Test\filename.txt").CreationTime=("21 December 2012 00:30:00")
```

- Change the **last write** date/timestamp of a file named `filename.txt`:

```
(Get-Item "D:\Test\filename.txt").LastWriteTime=("21 December 2012 00:30:00")
```

- Change the **last accessed** date/timestamp of a file named `filename.txt`:

```
(Get-Item "D:\Test\filename.txt").LastAccessTime=("21 December 2012 00:30:00")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have WSL with the appropriate distro like Ubuntu you can have the touch command in the CMD and not just the bash terminal. It works for me on Windows 10 & 11 Windows Terminal

Answer (score -1):

Easy, example with txt file

```
echo $null >> filename.txt
```

Comment: Adds `$null` to the file.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can use Node for Touch I just use that and its working all fine in windows Cmd or gitbash

[image]

Comment: I didn't downvote this but I'll explain why it probably was. This question was tagged with `[cmd]`, and that implies that the OP wants an answer that works out-of-the-box for CMD, meaning no command-line utilities that aren't packed with a default Windows install. That will exclude virtually all scripting languages, even built-in Windows scripting languages like CScript, WScript, and PowerShell. The point is not that it works in the CMD env, but that its possible for anyone with access to CMD, not including permissions issues.