# How can i create an empty file using a batch command?

Tags: windows, batch-file

So far my project is all about creating files for an imaginary game and I have to create files (and files within files), first, I have to ask them what version they want, and then the batch will create new files on my computer.

I just want to know what is the command to create new files, no need for other info.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.

```
type nul > your_file.txt
```

It is already resolved here

[Windows equivalent of 'touch' (i.e. the node.js way to create an index.html)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30011267/windows-equivalent-of-touch-i-e-the-node-js-way-to-create-an-index-html).

Comment: I would argue that touch is mostly used for changing time stamps of files.  The copy command can be used to touch a file without modifying to to change the time stamp.