# Windows 10 dot local redirection not behaving as I expected

Tags: dll, windows-10

We are using an earlier version of a commercial application, doors.exe. The latest Windows 10 update broke it. Using msftedit.dll from Windows 7 restores it. Below are three scenarios I have tried. I don't understand why the first and last function the way they do rather than the way the documentation seems to say they should. Questions are in the first and last bullet.

- If I create a directory doors.exe.local in the same location as the doors.exe executable and put the win7 dll into that directory, it is ignored and the one in SysWOW64 is used. Why isn't it using the .local directory?
- If I put the win7 dll in the same directory as doors.exe, the win7 is used, whether or not I have an empty file named doors.exe.local.
- If I put win7 dll into the doors.exe directory but don't create doors.exe.local redirect file, I expect that doors.exe would use whatever dll is loaded and only use the win7 dll if nothing was loaded. If I first start WordPad, which also uses msftedit.dll, and then start doors.exe, doors.exe still uses the local msftedit.dll. Why isn't it using the same dll as wordpad?

I am using Process Explorer to see exactly which dll is used by which process.

The above behavior seems contrary to what I have read in the MSDN documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dlls/dynamic-link-library-redirection

What am I missing/not understanding?

Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 1):

I found how Dynamic-Link Library Redirection/Dot Local works. It uses some sort of caching per .exe instance to mark if redirection is used or not.

When you have an app.exe, first time when you run it on your PC it marks if it will use Redirection or not. Later this decision remains regardless if you put or remove the app.exe.local file/folder. I do not know yet where the cache value is stores. I searched the registry for the cache but haven't fount it.

**Example 1**: If you have app.exe and you do not have app.exe.local next to it and you run it first time, later never will use redirection. If you add app.exe.local redirection will not work.

**Exsmple 2**: If you have app.exe and you do have the app.exe.local next to it and you run it first time, later always will apply redirection. If you remove app.exe.local it still applies redirection.

I do not see the motivation for this confusing behavior.

Useful: if you want to reset the cache for an exe to use redirection or not, you can run in cmd:

```
touch app.exe
```

Comment: There is no "touch" command in windows. Did you try this yourself and get it to work?

Comment: Ahh. It is from mingw. Here are described some alternatives https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30011267/windows-equivalent-of-touch-i-e-the-node-js-way-to-create-an-index-html

Answer (score 0):

Do you know if the msftedit.dll is loaded with relative path? Or simpler, just by name? What you describe matches the standard LoadLibrary search order. First is the current working directory.

I am struggling with local redirection too. I have 3 PC where it works and 1 where doesn't.

Comment: According to this [https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order), "If a DLL with the same module name is already loaded in memory, the system checks only for redirection and a manifest before resolving to the loaded DLL, no matter which directory it is in. The system does not search for the DLL." It shouldn't have reacted the way it did in my third bullet, and the .local file/directory should have changed the order. I don't know how the msftedit.dll is loaded.