# 'touch' not recognized as internal or external command'

Tags: python, django, command

I am attempting to create a django app but I am getting the 'touch' not recognized as internal or external command' error.

```
   C:\Users\blake\Documents\ProgrammingProjects\orwell84\apps> touch __init__.py
  'touch' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
   operable program or batch file.
```

my python version is 3.7.3 and my django version is 2.2.4 . Am I missing something ?

Comment: Touch is a UNIX command, it is not available on windows but it is not related to python or django. For alternatives to touch see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30011267/windows-equivalent-of-touch-i-e-the-node-js-way-to-create-an-index-html

Comment: Most Django tutorials I've seen assume you're using a Unix-like OS (Mac, Linux, Ubuntu, ...). So, for any command-line stuff, you'll typically need to do a small amount of translation to get the tutorials to work on Windows :-(. If you don't want to deal with this, you might give something like [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/install.html) a shot. Or, look into setting up a virtual machine.

Answer (score 1):

Touch is the command specific to `Linux` and `unix` and not to `Windows`. Not to `Django` either (which is a framework).

If you want to create an empty file here's the command.

```
notepad __init__.py
```