# Is there a quick way to enable install tool in TYPO3?

Tags: xampp, typo3, typo3-10.x

Is there a quick way to enable install tool in TYPO3?

Please share a command for Windows. The one I have access to is for Linux I think.

I am using Windows and need to enable install tool to access TYPO3 panel..

Comment: _The one I have access to is for Linux I think..._ and you assume we're operators of the **glass ball** and we can guess what you have on your Win? These things are described in doc's and they are OS independent if docs say you need to create `ENABLE_INSTALL_TOOL` as Bernrd pointed, you just need to create it, end of magic. While you're using Win OS, you can use Explorer for this. For UNIX-like OS it would be just one command in terminal: (assuming you're in your TYPO3 project's root already): `touch typo3conf/ENABLE_INSTALL_TOOL`

Answer (score 2):

you need to create a file `ENABLE_INSTALL_TOOL` in the `typo3conf/` folder of your webspace. the content doesn't matter. it does not need to be an empty file.

you have multiple options:

1. create a new file with the windows file explorer. make sure you have no file extension!
2. use a shell/commandline: `echo anything > ENABLE_INSTALL_TOOL` while in the apropriate path
3. use any programm to store files. make sure to remove any file extension.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you to "touch" the Install Tool file `ENABLE_INSTALL_TOOL`: [Windows equivalent of 'touch' (i.e. the node.js way to create an index.html)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30011267/windows-equivalent-of-touch-i-e-the-node-js-way-to-create-an-index-html)