# I can't create a global gitignore in my terminal. touch ~/.gitignore gives an error

Tags: cmder

I am trying to create a global .gitignore file with  this command:

**touch ~/.gitignore**

but in my terminal (Cmder) gives this message: "touch: cannot touch '~/.gitignore': No such file or directory"

I have changed to windows terminal default (Command Prompt) and it says:
"'touch' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

What I am doing wrong or what can I do to solve this?

Comment: If you work on windows there is no "touch" command. Check this question for alternatives https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30011267/windows-equivalent-of-touch-i-e-the-node-js-way-to-create-an-index-html

Comment: @DanielCamarda `cmder` has the touch command though

Comment: I have touch command in Cmder. The problem is not touch but this : ~/.gitignore

Comment: voiting to close in favor of question posted by Daniel, which contains answer in more detail.

Comment: As @eis pointed out the problem may be in the path part of the command. If Cmder supports "touch" try  "touch C:\something.txt" and check if it works.

Comment: Yes the problem is not in command touch , it is in  the ~/.gitignore. Because with Cmder I create my files with touch command without any problem at all. So my question is not the same of the links Daniel.

Comment: @RaquelSantos have you tried `touch "%USERPROFILE%\.gitignore"`

Comment: @eis I think this is the answer . I wrote that and found a text  file in my user profile .Is that it?

Comment: yes, that is what it's meant to do. added to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using linux syntax. Now, even though `touch` is not understood by cmd prompt, it is a command understood by `cmder` but expression `~/.gitignore` is still linux way of saying things.

What you can do on cmd prompt, <strike>I guess also would work on cmder</strike> (edit: doesn't seem to work for cmder):

```
copy con "%USERPROFILE%\.gitignore"
[press F6 and enter after that]
```

For cmder, this could work:

```
touch "%USERPROFILE%\.gitignore"
```

Comment: copy con "%USERPROFILE%\.gitgnore"
[press F6 and enter after that]  
I didnt understood.  You are saying that I write in cmder  "%USERPROFILE%\.gitignore" without touch at the beggining? And then press F6 and enter?

Comment: @RaquelSantos first line is what you write to cmd prompt, then press enter, then you need to press F6 and again enter

Comment: You are saying that I write in cmder "%USERPROFILE%\.gitignore" without touch at the beggining? And then press F6 and enter?

Comment: yes, that is what I'm saying. it is cmd prompt way of doing things, and I think it would also work on cmder.

Comment: ok, then cmder doesn't work this way. Recommend using cmd prompt.

Answer (score 0):

This should help for windows terminal:

echo $null >> pot.txt

touch is linux command not windows command.

Below question should help a lot more :
https://superuser.com/questions/502374/equivalent-of-linux-touch-to-create-an-empty-file-with-powershell

Comment: $null is not windows either, I wonder what you intended that to contain?

Comment: echo is not windows either. but cmder  emulator has those commands . I use touch to create files. If I create a normal file it works., What doesnt work is  writting this after touch  command ~/.gitignore

Comment: @RaquelSantos echo certainly is windows stuff (also)