# Why am I getting Access Denied when writing files to a network path when my user account can create files

Tags: c#, file, writeallbytes

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(NetworkPath, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringBuilder.ToString()));
```

When running this code in Visual Studio, I get Access Denied.

However if I navigate to Network Path with File Explorer, I can right click and create Files and Folders with the same User account that is running Visual Studio 2019 and the code above.

Comment: Try running vs as administrator

Comment: Is the file opened by some other (or your) app?

Comment: What sort of app are you creating? For instance a Web app may run as a special account, without network rights

Comment: It's txt files being created but the files never get created so ... no it's not being held open by another application.

Comment: Impersonating some account? The code shown doesn't have any problems writing to a network path. Are you using UNC path or a mapped network drive?

Comment: @Steeeve I am using a DFS path \\servername\foldername\file.txt

Comment: @softwareisfun What happens if you [touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30011267/create-an-empty-file-on-the-commandline-in-windows-like-the-linux-touch-command) that DFS path from the command line?

Comment: @TechInquisitor everything works from Windows or the Operating System. It's from C# (Visual Studio), I get Access Denied.

Comment: The comment about project type is probably relevant.

Comment: OT simpler suggestion: [File.WriteAllText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=net-5.0#System_IO_File_WriteAllText_System_String_System_String_System_Text_Encoding_) - not that that will help you with your network issues, alas