# What is the 'touch' command equivalent in Windows Terminal?

Tags: windows, terminal, command-line

I'm trying to make a new folder in the directory I just created and in the tutorial video they told me to use 'touch example.js' but I get the error 'touch: The term "touch" is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

I haven't tried anything else but decided to come here to see if I could receive a quick answer.

Comment: [Create an empty file on the commandline in windows (like the linux touch command)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30011267/995714), [Windows equivalent of the Linux command 'touch'?](https://superuser.com/q/10426/241386), [windows equivalent to touch](https://superuser.com/q/1784460/241386)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create an empty file on the commandline in windows (like the linux touch command)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30011267/create-an-empty-file-on-the-commandline-in-windows-like-the-linux-touch-command)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in linux, `touch` command is typically used to create an empty file, not a directory! but in Windows Command Prompt(`CMD`) you can do like this to make a folder :

```
mkdir your_folder_name
```

or you can do it in Windows `PowerShell` like this

```
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Name your_folder_name
```

but if you want to create a new file with for example `.txt` extension, you can use the `echo` command like this in `CMD`:

```
echo. > my_empty_file.txt
```

or in `PowerShell` like this:

```
"" > my_empty_file.txt
```

good luck !

Answer (score 0):

The `touch` command is typically used to create an empty file. As an alternative, on Windows, you can use something like this:

```
type nul > example.js
```

It will create an empty file called `example.js` in your current directory.

Comment: Tried it out. Thanks!